# How do I create an image with blurred background and focused foreground?

Tags: background, photoshop-effects, photography, focus

[EveryMe.com](http://everyme.com/) uses this image as background:

[image: EveryMe.com background]

How is it done, and how do I edit an image to look like that?

I use Pixelmator and photoshop, thanks!

Comment: Are you certain the blurred effect in the original is the result of image manipulation?  It seems more likely to me that it was done by simply adjusting aperture to narrow the depth of field while taking the photograph. (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field#Limited_DOF:_selective_focus)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This background looks like it was created with the Lens Blur filter in Photoshop, with a high radius and with specular highlights set to 0. Shape Blur could also get this effect, using an elliptical solid shape. It doesn't look like in-camera blur, and it certainly isn't gaussian blur.

The hand with phone and the face of the phone are separate images composited together, which were then composited onto the background, making it easy to adjust and blur the background to fit the needs of the composition, which also suggests that the blurring was done in post.

Either way, it's very important to add noise after the blurring, which wipes out the noise, so the background looks like it belonged to the foreground. (Actually, the designer in this case overdid it slightly. The background has more and different noise than the hand so that they are subtly, visually disconnected by that as well as the lighting. That's what gives the overall image its artificial look.)

If this was a smart designer, the noise was added by creating a 50% gray layer in Overlay mode and running Filter > Noise > Add Noise, with Uniform and Monochrome both selected.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'd be taking the photo using a lens with a shallow dpeth of field to bring your foreground into focus but nothing else.

To fake it, you need to spend some time masking out your foreground, then applying various degrees of gaussian blur to the rest of the photo.

Comment: Gaussian blur yes, or, when in Photoshop: `Filters` → `Blur` → `Lens blur…` for more lifelike simulation.

Answer (score 2):

according to me Phone in hand and the background both is placed differently its not created with the help of filters.... first they worked on background with filters and then they placed the Hand with the phone to look prominent....

we have multiple way of doing the same,all you need is to be specific in your selection after that leave everything on Filters in your example image,all details is depend on selection the perfect you select the more detail you'll get.

i am attaching some ss please check if they can help you...!

Mine editing and selection is bit ugly/poor sorry for that :| all i want to show you the way of doing its easy..... :|

---

[image]

after selecting your desired place which you want to highlight (mine is mobile),select invert and go to the filters > blur > Gaussian blur,

[image]

you can also use lens blur go to filters > blur > lens blur,
[image]

So there are lots of other way to do the same, using all this is the easier method...Hope they will help....

you can also use lens blur go to filters > blur > Motion blur

[image]

play with sliders to get your desired effect

---

For more details on blurring background with photoshop see these tutorials may be one of them will help you :

1. [Background blur in Photoshop](http://www.digiretus.com/tippek/cikkiro.php?SORSZAM=11)
2. [Motion Blur in Photoshop](http://www.tutorialsroom.com/tutorials/graphics/motion_blur.html)
3. [Photoshop radial blur tutorial](http://www.graphicmania.net/photoshop-blur-filters-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in Pixelmator is the Blur tool called Miniaturize. Essentially you can set this to an elliptical setting, and drag it to be the size of the phone in this case, and adjust things like transiton, blur etc.

In one of our tutorials on creating photorealistic perspective in Pixelmator, we use this tool. 
http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/pixelmator-tip-8-how-to-add-photorealistic-perspective/

PN.